# How can I play FLV video in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to streaming flv video in Media Element in WP8. But I can't play an video (flv). Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, FLV is not supported in Windows Phone. You have to go for alternative.

Answer (score 2):

WP doesn't support flv but on your server you can convert flv video to mp4 and streaming it.